# Estimating the number of pairs of primes $p < q$ with $pq\le n$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Given a natural number $n$, how many pairs $p,q$ of distinct primes (WLOG take $p < q$) with $pq\le n$?

I have an expression (below) for this quantity, but I am seeking a sharp upper bound.

**Attempt:**

Group the products in the following way: $$2\cdot 3, 2\cdot 5, \cdots2P_2\\3\cdot 5, 3\cdot 7,\ldots 3P_3\\
5\cdot 7, 5\cdot 11, \ldots, 5P_5 ,$$

where $P_2$ is the largest prime with $2P_2\le n$; i.e., $P_2$ is the largest prime $\le \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$; $P_3$ is the largest prime $\le \lfloor n/3 \rfloor $, and so on. In order to count the number of products $\le n$, I count them by the rows listed above.

Letting $\pi(\cdot)$ denote the prime counting function, the first row has $\pi(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)-1$ many elements (the minus one is included since $2\cdot2$ is not in the list), the 2nd row has $\pi(\lfloor n/3\rfloor)-2$ many elements (the minus two is included since $3\cdot3$, $3\cdot5$ are not in the list), and so on. Letting $p_i$ denote the $i$th prime,
the desired sum is

$$\sum \left( \pi \left( \lfloor n/p_i \rfloor \right)-i \right),$$

where the sum is over all $i$ such that $p_ip_{i+1}\le n$. The constraint $p_i p_{i+1}\le n$ is needed since we only are allowed start counting in row $i$ if $p_ip_{i+1}\le n.$

I would like a sharp upper bound if possible, but I am unsure of how to estimate $i$ from $n$.

Comment: What does the totient function have to do with products of primes?

Comment: Oops, I meant the primepi function, I will fix that.

Comment: Sieve of Sundaram $n=4a^2+4a+1$

Comment: The function $\pi$ is defined for all reals so there's no need of the floor, just write $\pi(n/p_i)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum you got may be simplified as $$\sum_{p\le\sqrt{n}}\pi(n/p)-\frac{\pi(\sqrt{n})(\pi(\sqrt{n})+1)}{2}$$

It's asymptotic to $\frac{n \log\log n}{\log{n}}$.